# How to move the cursor on a dropdown using selenium/C#

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

Have a field that has a dropdown with five choices. Clicking the field will display the drop-down. Need to move the cursor to the third field and then click on it.
Example. the field is called product name and drop-down has "select Option", "apple", "banana", "grape", "mango" and "pineapple", in that order. "select Option" is default and need to select grape, by moving the cursor. Need to click and open the drop-down, move the cursor to grape (which high lights it) and click on it. The below code does not move the cursor to the correct location (visually should see) and then throws an exception: "ElementNotInteractableException". Any ideas on how to do it and why the exception is thrown? In the menu pic. shown below, the blue highlight should be moved to the yellow highlight. **Is it possible to accomplish with say JavaScriptExecutor or some other way**?

```
            ProductName.Click();
            var opt = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[text()='Grape']"));
            Actions mouse = new(DriverContext.Driver);
            mouse.MoveToElement(opt);
            mouse.Click();
            mouse.Perform();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Selenium provides a package to interact with dropdown/select elements. See: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/working_with_select_elements/

Works better than mouse actions, also gives options to read out selected elements.
Example:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
IWebElement selectElement = 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//<path to dropdown>")); 
var selectObject = new SelectElement(selectElement);
selectObject.SelectByText("Bread")
```

Note that you need to find the select element, not the options withtin it.